# PHP converting of int to string

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to parse out my if-else statements nicely but it seems that it doesn't parse out the else statement.

```
$a = 1
if (is_numeric($a)) 
{
    $DB = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
    $result = $DB->query('select id from staff where id='.$a);
        if ($result == "")
        {
        echo "'{$a}' is invalid. No such record", PHP_EOL;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "'{$a}' is found", PHP_EOL; 
        }

} 
else 
{
    echo "'{$a}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
}
```

My $result I think it will return in Integer as when I say to echo the $ result out, it says PDO statement cannot be converted to INT.
It doesn't go to my first inner else statement. Please advise how did I make my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: can you make a var_dump($result); before the if-else?

Comment: $result is an object not a string, if you want to fetch a row and check that, you need to call a method of result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$result` is an object, not a integer. You need to call a fetch method, such as `fetchAll`, or even simplier, `fetch` to put the datas into another variable.

Try with :

```
$a = 1
if (is_numeric($a)) 
{
    $DB = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
    $result = $DB->query('select id from staff where id='.$a);
        if ($result)
        {
            $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            if (!isset($data[0]))
                echo "'{$a}' is invalid. No such record", PHP_EOL;
            else
                echo "'{$a}' is found", PHP_EOL; 
        }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "'{$a}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here's another example with `fetch` :

```
$a = 1
if (is_numeric($a)) 
{
    $DB = new PDO('sqlite:database.db');
    $result = $DB->query('select id from staff where id='.$a);
        if ($result)
        {
            $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (!$data)
                echo "'{$a}' is invalid. No such record", PHP_EOL;
            else
                echo "'{$a}' is found", PHP_EOL; 
        }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "'{$a}' is NOT numeric", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working thanks! But i won't want to fetch all records. Only want that particular record matching to the database actually. Any idea to fetch one ?

Comment: You may want to use `fetch`. Have a look at the php manual page : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I must say you are my savior! Previously I tried fetch_assoc() then it cannot be found. THANKS so much!